# How to restart the Python script automatically if it is killed or dies

Tags: bash, shell, cron, python

I am running my Python script in the background in my Ubuntu machine (12.04) like this -

```
nohup python testing.py > test.out &
```

Now, it might be possible that at some stage my above `Python script` can die for whatever reason.

So I am thinking to have some sort of `cron agent` in bash shell script which can restart my above Python script automatically if it is killed for whatever reason.

Is this possible to do? If yes, then what's the best way to solve these kind of problem?

**UPDATE:**

After creating the `testing.conf` file like this -

```
chdir /tekooz
exec python testing.py
respawn
```

I ran below sudo command to start it but I cannot see that process running behind using ps ax?

```
root@bx13:/bezook# sudo start testing
testing start/running, process 27794
root@bx13:/bezook# ps ax | grep testing.py
27806 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto testing.py
```

Any idea why px ax is not showing me anything? And how do I check whether my program is running or not?

This is my python script -

```
#!/usr/bin/python
while True:
    print "Hello World"
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On Ubuntu (until 14.04, 16.04 and later use systemd) can use upstart to do so, better than a cron job. You put a config setup in `/etc/init` and make sure you specify [respawn](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn)

It could be a minimal file `/etc/init/testing.conf` (edit as `root`):

```
chdir /your/base/directory
exec python testing.py
respawn
```

And you can test with `/your/base/directory/testing.py`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import time

with open('/var/tmp/testing.log', 'a') as fp:
    print(time.time(), 'done', file=fp)
    time.sleep(3)
```

and start with:

```
sudo start testing
```

and follow what happens (in another window) with:

```
tail -f /var/tmp/testing.log
```

and stop with:

```
sudo stop testing
```

You can also add `[start on][2]` to have the command start on boot of the system.

Comment: If you use a cron job then you'll want to either implement or find some code for robust PID file handling.  You want to have your service/script/daemon create a PID file (conventionally located under /var/run) and have its start-up code check if the file contents are stale (left by a killed process).  This sort of code is surprisingly difficult to write free of races and corner cases. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788411/check-to-see-if-python-script-is-running

Comment: @Zelda: Thanks for suggestion.. I am new to Linux/Unix world.. What type of changes I am supposed to make in `/etc/init` file? If you can provide step by step guide for me, then I will be able to learn something and do the right thing..

Comment: @Webby I made the answer more complete. If you do not want to open a file for output and rewrite your print statements you can do something like `sys.stdout = open(file_name, 'w')` at the beginning.

Comment: Thank You Zelda. Appreciated your help.. I updated the question with some details.. I am trying to do like this to see whether my testing.py is running or not.. It doesn't shows me whether it is running or not.. `px ax | grep testing.py`.. It is returning me nothing? Any idea why?

Comment: You should put the whole thing in a try/except clause and write to a logfile what exception was generated and that the program exits. Maybe the print statement does not work as it cannot write to stdout.

Comment: I'd just like to note that the default init system is now systemd, not upstart, which this answer relies on.

Answer (score 24):

You could also take a more shell oriented approach. Have your `cron` look for your script and relaunch it if it dies.

1. Create a new crontab by running `crontab -e`. This will bring up a window of your favorite text editor.
2. Add this line to the file that just opened

   ```
   */5 * * * * pgrep -f testing.py || nohup python /home/you/scripts/testing.py > test.out
   ```
3. Save the file and exit the editor.

You just created a new `crontab` which will be run every 5 minutes and launch your script unless it is already running. See [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/cron-every-5-minutes/) for a nice little tutorial on `cron`. The official Ubuntu docs on `cron` are [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

The actual command being run is `pgrep` which searches running processes for the string given in the command line. `pgrep foo` will search for a program named `foo` and return its [process identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier). `pgrep -f` makes it search the entire command line used to launch the program and not only the program name (useful because this is a python script).

The `||` symbol means "do this if the previous command failed". So, if your script is not running, the `pgrep` will fail since it will find nothing and your script will be launched.

Comment: Thank you.. But I am new to linux and unix so don't know where is crontab? Is this a file in my ubuntu machine somewhere?

Comment: @Webby see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks terdon.. I can run this command `crontab -e` from the directory where my python script is.. Correct?

Comment: @Webby you can run it from anywhere you want. `cron` is a scheduling daemon, it is a service that runs in the background. If your python script is not in your `$PATH` (if you can't launch it from anywhere but need to be in its directory) use the full path to the script as in my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Now it makes sense.. I just created a new crontab and edited the file by adding the same single line but for 1 minute.. I have already created a Hello World Python script revolving around while True named as testing.py.. After saving the crontab file, it should automatically start the testing.py after 1 minute? And then keep on checking every 1 minute whether python script is running or not? If yes, after saving the crontab -e file, I did ps ax | grep testing.py and I am not able to see any process for that?

Comment: @Webby exactly, yes. As long as you have given the correct path to the script. You can also add ` 2>/tmp/log` to the end of the cron line to capture any errors you might encounter in the file `/tmp/log`.

Comment: @Webby, it will check every 5 minutes, not every one. It should start after 5 minutes. If not, add ` 2>/tmp/log` to the cron line and check that file to see any errors.

Comment: Cron power is simply overwhelming. Thanks for this!

Comment: How do you ensure cron is using the right conda environment?

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal the same way you do when running your script. I don't use conda, but if you need to source a file like with a python venv, just do that in the cron file: `. /path/to/venv/bin/activate; script.py`.

Comment: is this line added above the scheduling lines? I have added a shebang in the actual ```.py``` file for now to use the right env. Thanks

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal sorry, I don't understand what you mean. This is part of the cron command. And of course you want a shebang, but I don't see why that would affect the environment. It is probably best if you ask a new question where you can explain the details of what you need.

Comment: I mean I've added a python env shebang inside of the python file, not the cron file. I have just followed the instructions in your answer but for some reason, my jobs don't start. I have added the correct minute so that they start on the next minute. Hmm

Comment: Great solution. If you are using `sudo crontab -e`, then `pgrep -f testing.py` will return the same as `sudo pgrep -f testing.py`, which returns the identifier of the `sudo pgrep -f testing.py` command, which is not what you want. However you can get similar behavior by using `pgrep -fa testing.py | grep -v pgrep` ie piping into grep and ignoring anything with pgrep

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't really use this for production, but you could:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
  nohup python testing.py >> test.out
done &
```

If, for any reason, python process exits, the shell loop will continue and restart it, appending to the `.out` file as desired. Nearly no overhead and takes very little time to set up.

Answer (score 7):

You can have the testing program redirect the output using a commandline option
and then use a simple python script to restart the program indefinitely:

```
import subprocess

while True:
    try:
        print subprocess.check_output(['python', 'testing.py'])
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

you can put this program in the background, and once you want to stop just pull it into the foreground and kill it.

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of ways to monitor and respawn processes under UNIX/Linux.  One of the oldest is a "respawn" entry in /etc/inittab ... if you're using the old SysV init system.  Another method is to use the supervisor daemon from DJ Bernstein's *daemontools* package.  Other options are to use features in Ubuntu *upstart* ... or *systemd* or others.

But you can look at [alternatives init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) and in the Python code for [Pardus: mudur](https://github.com/Pardus-Linux/mudur) daemon in particular.

If you decide to go with a cron job (and PID file handling) then consider reading this [PEP 3143](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/) and perhaps using its reference implementation.

As I alluded to in my other comments, robust PID file handling is tricky.  It's prone to races and corner cases.  It gets trickier if there's any chance that your PID file ends up on an NFS or other networked filesystem (some of the atomicity guarantees you get with the file handling semantics on proper *local* UNIX/Linux filesystems go away on some versions and implementations of NFS, for example).  Also the semantics around file locking under UNIX can be tricky. (Does an `flock` or `fcntl` lock get released promptly, in your target OS, when the process holding it is killed with SIGKILL, for example?).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use **[monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/)** Or [Process monitoring with ps-watcher](http://archive09.linux.com/feature/148189)

> Monit is an open source utility for managing and monitoring,
>   processes, programs, files, directories and filesystems on a UNIX
>   system. Monit conducts automatic maintenance and repair and can
>   execute meaningful causal actions in error situations.

Here is example for your scenario:

```
check process myprocessname
        matching "myprocessname"
        start program = "nohup /usr/bin/python /path/testing.py > /tmp/test.out &"
        stop program = "/usr/bin/killall myprocessname"
```

[Take look at monit examples](http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples)

Answer (score 1):

You need a supervisor, you can use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). It is python based supervisor, therefore easy to modify if you need to.

Control is with files with .ini file syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Terdon's answer, did not work for me, because
`pgrep -f testing.py` was never 'failing'. It would grab the pid for the cron job (because of the -f option). However, without the -f option pgrep won't find testing.py because there's no process called testing.py.

My solution to this was to change

```
pgrep -f testing.py
```

to

```
pgrep -f testing.py | pgrep python
```

this means the full crontab job would be:

```
*/5 * * * * pgrep -f testing.py | pgrep python || nohup python /home/you/scripts/testing.py > test.out
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, as a quick-fix, I wanted to keep my program running when it exited with en error or it was killed. 
On the other hand, I wanted to stop the execution when the program terminated correctly (return code = 0)

I have tested it on Bash. It should work fine in any other shell

```
#!/bin/sh

echo ""
echo "Use: $0 ./instagram.py"
echo ""

echo "Executing $1 ..."

EXIT_CODE=1
(while [ $EXIT_CODE -gt 0 ]; do
    $1
    # loops on error code: greater-than 0
    EXIT_CODE=$?
done)
```

Answer (score 0):

For terdon's answer, `pgrep -f testing.py` will never return false according to the comments in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014559/running-pgrep-in-a-crontab?noredirect=1&lq=1):

> I think the issue is that cron spawns a shell to run your command, and the arguments of that shell are matched by pgrep since you are using -f

For Matt's answer, `pgrep -f testing.py` is useless since `pgrep python` matches any running Python script. So if two Python script cronjob, the second cronjob will never run.

And then I found the solution to solve `pgrep -f testing.py` in the comment here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014559/running-pgrep-in-a-crontab?noredirect=1&lq=1

My cron for running two Python scripts:

```
* * * * * pgrep -f '^/usr/bin/python36 /home/ec2-user/myscript1\.py' || nohup /usr/bin/python36 /home/ec2-user/myscript1.py

0 * * * * pgrep -f '^/usr/bin/python36 /home/ec2-user/myscript2\.py' || nohup /usr/bin/python36 /home/ec2-user/myscript2.py
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu this works for me thanks to `--wait`

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
  sleep 5
  gnome-terminal --wait -- sh -c "python3 myscript.py 'myarg1'"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a Python module for that, [forever](https://pypi.org/project/forever/).

The advantage being, hopefully, in using the same language for both the code and the [watchdog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer). If it needs to be improved, one can find it in

```
cd $(python -c "import site; print(site.getusersitepackages())")
```

I'd install it with

```
python -mpip install --user --upgrade forever
```

and later use it with

```
python -mforever.run -t 9 -i 9 python script-to-watch.py
```

Comment: Note that this module doesn't wait till the script crashes. It automatically crashes the script after the interval and restarts the script!