# Watchdog for py script in archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, watchdog

I would like a method as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107939/how-to-restart-the-python-script-automatically-if-it-is-killed-or-dies) to set a watchdog to keep a python script alive, but in archlinux.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Solved using the example provided by smokes2345. I created a python_script.service in `/etc/systemd/system/` with the following content:

`[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/fernando/PycharmProjects/get_tweets/get_tweets.py
Restart=always`

Comment: In this case there's no need to specify the type as it defaults to simple.  From the docs: "If set to simple (the default if neither Type= nor BusName=, but ExecStart= are specified)..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a systemd service unit as described [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) and be sure to include the line "Restart=always".  Systemd is the Arch equivalent of upstart.  A minimal configuration would look like:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=<full path to script>
Restart=always
```

You may need to invoke the interpreter directly and provide your script as an argument depending on the shebang used in your script.